# Simple TensorFlow Linear Regression Returns "can't multiply sequence by non-int" ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-regression

I'm new to TensorFlow and creating linear regressions, but I'm not seeing my issue here. I followed [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linear-regression-using-tensorflow/) to create my first simple (univariate) linear regression model, but am running into the error:

**UPDATE WITH NEW PRINT OUTPUTS**

```
_x :  -1000
_y :  10
_x :  -900
_y :  12
_x :  -950
_y :  12
...
c :  nan
c dtype :  float32
Epoch 50 : cost = nan W = nan b = nan

_x :  -1000
_y :  10
_x :  -900
_y :  12
_x :  -950
_y :  12
...
c :  nan
c dtype :  float32
Epoch 100 : cost = nan W = nan b = nan
...
Epoch 150 : cost = nan W = nan b = nan
...
Epoch 200 : cost = nan W = nan b = nan
...
Epoch 450 : cost = nan W = nan b = nan
...
Epoch 500 : cost = nan W = nan b = nan
training_cost :  nan
training_cost dtype :  float32
weight :  nan
weight :  float32
bias :  nan
bias dtype :  float32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "editabletoworkouterrors.py", line 77, in <module>
    new_green_dur = green_light_duration_new(current_reward, current_green)
  File "editabletoworkouterrors.py", line 66, in green_light_duration_new
    green_light_duration_new = weight * x + bias
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float32'
```

So I have a bunch of nan's for some reason? When I tried this in the program I'm working on which has a large list of green light durations and rewards, sometimes it'll start with having numbers in the weight, x and b values as it should, but then it starts displaying nan's again during the later epochs, if that makes sense?

I'm making a traffic simulator, and I'd like it to be able to determine what the best "green light duration" would be, based on a previous reward (car wait time change for the lane in the reward). I've created a simple working code for someone to replicate:

**UPDATED WITH NEW PRINTS IN CODE**

```
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='once', category=FutureWarning) # future warnings annoy me

# set the epsilon for this episode

# Start with empty lists
reward = []
green_light = []

# add in a couple of rewards and light durations
current_reward = [-1000,-900,-950]
current_green = [10,12,12]

# Pass in reward and green_light
def green_light_duration_new(current_reward, current_green):
    # Predicting the best light duration based on previous rewards.
    # predict the best duration based on previous step's reward value, using simple linear regression model
    x = current_reward
    y = current_green
    n = len(x)
    # Plot of Training Data  
    plt.scatter(x, y) 
    plt.xlabel('Reward') 
    plt.ylabel('Green Light Duration') 
    plt.title("Training Data") 
    plt.show() 

    X = tf.placeholder("float") 
    Y = tf.placeholder("float") 
    W = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name = "W") 
    b = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(), name = "b") 
    learning_rate = 0.01
    training_epochs = 500
    # Hypothesis 
    y_pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b) 
    print('y_pred : ', y_pred)
    print('y_pred dtype : ', y_pred.dtype)
    # Mean Squared Error Cost Function 
    cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(y_pred-Y, 2)) / (2 * n)
    print('cost : ', cost)
    print('cost dtype: ', cost.dtype)
    # Gradient Descent Optimizer 
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)    
    # Global Variables Initializer 
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    # Starting the Tensorflow Session 
    with tf.Session() as sess: 
        # Initializing the Variables 
        sess.run(init) 
        # Iterating through all the epochs 
        for epoch in range(training_epochs): 
            # Feeding each data point into the optimizer using Feed Dictionary 
            for (_x, _y) in zip(x, y): 
                print('_x : ',_x)
                print('_y : ',_y)
                sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {X : _x, Y : _y}) 
            # Displaying the result after every 50 epochs 
            if (epoch + 1) % 50 == 0: 
                # Calculating the cost a every epoch 
                c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {X : x, Y : y}) 
                print('c : ', c)
                print('c dtype : ', c.dtype)
                print("Epoch", (epoch + 1), ": cost =", c, "W =", sess.run(W), "b =", sess.run(b)) 
        # Storing necessary values to be used outside the Session 
        training_cost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict ={X: x, Y: y}) 
        print('training_cost : ', training_cost)
        print('training_cost dtype : ', training_cost.dtype)
        weight = sess.run(W)
        print('weight : ', weight)
        print('weight : ', weight.dtype)
        bias = sess.run(b)
        print('bias : ', bias)
        print('bias dtype : ', bias.dtype)
    # Calculating the predictions 
    green_light_duration_new = weight * x + bias 
    print("Training cost =", training_cost, "Weight =", weight, "bias =", bias, '\n')
    # Plotting the Results 
    plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', label ='Original data') 
    plt.plot(x, green_light_duration_new, label ='Fitted line') 
    plt.title('Linear Regression Result') 
    plt.legend() 
    plt.show() 
    return green_light_duration_new

# Go to the training function
new_green_dur = green_light_duration_new(current_reward, current_green)

# Append the predicted green light to its list
green_light.append(new_green_dur)

# Go on to run the rest of the simulation with the new green light duration,
# and append its subsequent reward to current_reward list to run again later.
```

Also, if there's a way for the regression model to keep the green light duration to be between a minimum of 10 (seconds) and a maximum value of 120 seconds, that would be spectacular too, I just don't know how to work that in. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It appears that `weight` is not a recognized vector type.  Thus, when you multiply `weight * x`, Python believes that you're trying to replicate a sequence, rather than doing a vector*scalar operation.  Use a couple of `print` statements to trace the provenance (type & value) of each variable.

Comment: Or is it the 'c' that's causing the issue? I've updated my code above to include a bunch of prints of the variables and their dtypes to help pinpoint where I'm going wrong. Thanks! @Prune

Comment: And where is the output from those `print` commands?  Please update that part of the post, as well.

Comment: @Prune up there now. The code should replicate the output on your end. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.  It helps because my Python-enabled machine is currently upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... and there's the problem!  Current values of items are

```
x = [-1000,-900,-950]    # type list
weight = nan             # type numpy.float32
bias   = nan             # type numpy.float32
```

`x` is a simple Python list, *not* a numpy array.  Python doesn't have vectorized operations such as `float * list`

Comment: Ugh! Smacks forehead. Thanks for the help. When I get back to it later today, I’ll convert the lists to Numpy arrays and retest. I’ll mark your answer as complete after that. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: Ok, so it works, sort of. It gets through to the end and plots the original data points, but doesn't plot the line of best fit, and I'm still getting nan values for Cost, W and b. Any ideas? Keep in mind, I'm new to TensorFlow and I'm not exactly grasping what's happening here :(

Comment: (1) The `nan` values would be a different problem -- another posting.  (2) I won't be able to reproduce this until I get my Python platform fully rebased to 3.7.  However, if you post a separate question to focus on the `nan` values, I expect that someone else will pick up the issue.